# HTML table responsive 100% width

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to make a simple HTML table responsive by giving the 2 tds 100% width at smaller screen sizes, I have this so far...

```css
.test1{
background:teal;
text-align:center;
padding:20px;
}

.test2 {
background:tan;
padding:20px;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%;">
<tr>
<td style="width:300px;" class="test1">Test Content</td>
<td style="width:300px;" class="test2">Test Content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I have tried changing the width to 100% but that isn't working for me, what is the easiest way of doing this in CSS only?  I have no control over the HTML table that is generated.

Can I apply flexbox styling to a table?

Comment: HTML comes with that inline style? You said you have no control over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **media** query then change your width screen size

```css
.test1 {
        background: teal;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    .test2 {
        background: tan;
        padding: 20px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    @media (max-width: 700px) {

        .test1, .test2 {
            width: 100% !important;
            float: left;
        }
    }
```

```html
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:300px;" class="test1">Test Content</td>
        <td style="width:300px;" class="test2">Test Content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

so when width screen max **700px** then

[image]

and when more then **700px** then

[image]

you can add more media query as your requirement .

For more information

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp